# Transpose Rows to Columns for the same ID

Tags: sql-server

I have table called  equipment.

> Unit_ID   SensorSerial 
>  1 
>               11 
>  1
>                22 
>   1              33
>   
>  2             
>   44 
>  2            
>    55 
>  2          
>      66 
>  3        
>        77 
>  3      
>          88 
>  3    
>            99

I would like to make query to have following table:

> Unit_ID   Sensor1   Sensor2
>     Sensor3
>  1        
>        11         
>    22          
>    33
>  2          
>      44         
>    55          
>    66
>  3          
>      77         
>    88          
>    99

Comment: So what have you tried so far? StackOverflow is a place where you can ask concrete question and get answer on it, but not a "code writing service"

Comment: You can use PIVOT tables.

Comment: If there exits a fourth sensor for the Unit_ID 1. How you show them.(Is the number of sensors are constant(3))

Comment: I have a Sensor_ID as well but it is 1,2,3 for unit_id=1; 4,5,6,for unit_id=2; 7,8,9 for unit_ID=3. Anyway number of sensor is constant and equal to 3.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
select Unit_ID,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then SensorSerial end) as Sensor1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then SensorSerial end) as Sensor2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then SensorSerial end) as Sensor3       
from (select equipment.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by Unit_ID order by SensorSerial) as seqnum
      from equipment
     ) equipment
group by Unit_ID;
```

Comment: Remove the alise name 't' in subquery(t.*).

Comment: @Kumar No, then group by not worked?Better, if you try query on local

Comment: @Pedro - If this serve's your need means then mark it as answer.

Comment: @NoDisplayName...Aggreed